# Using arc.Centroid to put an svg:image in the middle of the arc - but not appearing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to place a svg:image in the centre of my arc:

```
  var arcs = svg.selectAll("path");

arcs.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg ")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
.attr("width", "150px") 
.attr("height", "200px");
```

I would appreciate it if someone could give me any advice on why it isn't appearing

thanks : http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the jsfiddle, you are creating the `path` elements after you try to append the `svg:image` elements to the them. It should be the other way around. You should first create the arcs and then append the images.

Second, as far as I know, the `svg:path` element should not contain any `svg:image` tags. It doesn't seem to display them if you place some inside. Instead what you should do is create `svg:g` tags with class `arc` and then use those to place the `svg:images`

Slightly modifying your jsfiddle could look something like this:

```
var colours = ['#909090','#A8A8A8','#B8B8B8','#D0D0D0','#E8E8E8'];

var arcs = svg.selectAll("path");

for (var z=0; z<30; z++){
   arcs.data(donut(data1))
      .enter()
      //append the groups
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "arc")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return colours[(Math.floor(z/6))]; })
      .attr("d", arc[z])
      .attr("stroke","black")
} 

//here we append images into arc groups
var pics = svg.selectAll(".arc").append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg ")
   .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
       //since you have an array of arc generators I used i to find the arc
       return "translate(" + arc[i].centroid(d) + ")"; })
   .attr("x",-5)
   .attr("y",-10)
   .attr("width", "10px") 
   .attr("height", "20px");
```

Where I also decreased the size of the images and offset them so that they fit into the arc.

Comment: Hi, thanks cyon, but I only wish to place svg:image within the centre of the arc - where the circles are at the moment, is that possible? Then I would eventually like to begin to move the circles/names actually into the arc as you have just done. The one shape will be placed in one of the 'V' shapes.

Comment: Oh, in that case you might be able to do `svg.append("svg:image")`, to put it in the same group as the pie chart. You may have to make the image smaller and give it some negative displacement with `attr` "x" and `attr` "y".

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick! Although when I've tried to do the same to the circles, they lose the names & have a strange outline? Any ideas... http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/20/